# Possible inconsistencies of lesser forest wyverns that camouflage/communicate by changing skin color/patterns

Tags: biology, creature-design

I wanted some feedback on a forest predator species I thought of that would be the equivalent of wolves on my world.

Like the title suggests, this species would be based on wyverns, but only in that they are lizards that have wing-based front limbs, they wouldn't breath fire or anything.

The main advantages that they would have is that they are pack predators and they can change their skin color (or scale color, if you will) as well as make patterns to work as camouflage as well as communicate with each other. They wouldn't be able to turn any color though, they could only change to different shades of brown.

Can you think of anything that would be a problem?

Comment: Why only brown?  Anoles can turn green and brown.

Comment: Honestly, whenever I think of wyverns I can only really think of the many types in 'monster hunter'. Though you might want to look at psuedo or other lesser wyverns for reference, the rathians' backflip is still OP.

Comment: @Necessity I can only think of the road I used to live on. I never knew wyverns were a mythical creature before.

Answer (score 4):

**In short, not great for a hunting species if their only communication is color**
My first concern is communication during night time, which would be difficult at best (discerning different shades of brown from a distance).
The second issue I see is the interference, sure the wyverns could encode a QR code on themselves, but would this be clear from 20m through dense foliage, or at any distance outside of line of sight? Also how would they decode this message easily while moving. While hunting it is very likely the wyverns will not be able to maintain visual contact at a distance, let alone run a decoding process.
 
The final issue I can see is bandwidth. Assuming the wyverns use a simple morse code system (dark brown on, light brown off), which would be the easiest system I could think of (largest area to see signal, either one color or the other), Wikipedia lists morse code normally at between 13 and 20 words per minute, which isn't great if you need to say "Hey Walter, go behind that creature and attack when he steps over the ledge".
**But**
If they have other ways of communicating this could be perfectly fine for simple signalling if line of sight could be maintained.
*As a suggestion, consider adding bioluminescence, then they can trigger this in a pattern that is visible at night, and for added stealth make this in a wavelength that their pray cant see (think infrared). Then make them evolved to decode these signals through patches on their skin (removing the need for looking at each other).*

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=binary+star+system+is%3Aq) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=binary+star+system+is%help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!